# не могу присвоить данные полученные через fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

присвоиваю данные полученные с fetch но они не присваиваются

```
getPosts(){

    this.$loader.classList.add('visible');

    let url = './assets/blog/find-posts.php';

    let start = this.startPostPosition;
    let end   = this.endPostPosition;

    let data  = new FormData();
    data.append('start', start);
    data.append('end', end);

    fetch(url, {
        method : 'POST',
        body   : data
    })
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( data  => this.posts = data )
    .then( () => {
        this.startPostPosition += this.step;
        this.endPostPositiotn  += this.step;
    })
    console.log(this.posts)
}
```

посты точно приходят проверял, в после this.posts равен пустому массиву.

Также this.startPostPosition, this.endPostPosition не изменяются

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает, оказывается я проверял не дождавшись ответа